# Email Address updated in Sales Cloud, MC Email sent to Old Email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have configured MC Connector with our Sales Cloud and MC instance and it works fine. We are using Data Stream to get Contacts data from Sales Cloud into Marketing Cloud.

The problem arises when a Contact's email address is updated in Sales Cloud but the email that is sent out from a Journey to the Contact uses his previous email address.

I understand, that the Journey is looking at the 'All Subscribers' list while sending email.

Is there a way (other than manually updating the 'All Subscribers' list), that can ensure the email goes to the Contact on his new email address and not the one in 'All Subscribers' list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a scheduled automation that reads the updates from the synchronized data extensions and writes them to the All Subscribers list.

The necessary activities in the automation are:

- **SQL Query activity** (checks for changed email addresses in sales/service cloud)
- **Data Extract activity** (extracts data from temporary data extension and writes it to csv (unfortunately this is necessary for importing into All Subscribers))
- **File Transfer activity** (moves the csv from the Export to the Import folder of your enhanced FTP)
- **Import File activity** (reads the updates from the csv file and writes them to All Subscribers)

The query for the first activity looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    sfdc.Id as SubscriberKey,
    sfdc.Email as EmailAddress,
    allsub.Status
FROM
    Contact_Salesforce as sfdc
RIGHT JOIN
    _subscribers as allsub
ON sfdc.Id = allsub.SubscriberKey
WHERE sfdc.Email != allsub.EmailAddress
```

*Note:* If you are in a multi-org setup you need to use `ent.[Contact_Salesforce]` instead of `Contact_Salesforce` in your query.

Detailed information can be found on my blog in the article ["How to sync email address changes from Sales/Service Cloud to All Subscribers list in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?"](https://markus.codes/2017/07/14/how-to-sync-email-changes-from-service-cloud-to-all-subscribers-list).

Comment: That seems to be a great solution. Thanks for the quick turnaround @Markus. I will give this a shot and post my results here.

Comment: You are welcome, Nikhil!